# Simple Scala XML parsing

Tags: xml, scala, date, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an XML file containing a couple hundred messages like the following, denoting passage times of a car at checkpoints.

```
<ttt:appMsg xmlns:ttt="railrt/ttt/v0100" channel="rct" id="019176" time="2016-06-08T06:01:01.260">
<rct:st prodDatum="2016-06-08" Number="62713">
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:28:02" pbpID="RY@P121" pdt="2016-06-08T04:28:02"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:28:11" pbpID="RY@P5215" pdt="2016-06-08T04:28:13"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:28:31" pbpID="RY@P5221" pdt="2016-06-08T04:28:31"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:28:40" pbpID="RY@P5223" pdt="2016-06-08T04:28:41"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:28:47" pbpID="RY@P5233" pdt="2016-06-08T04:28:49"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:28:56" pbpID="RY@P5241" pdt="2016-06-08T04:28:56"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:29:04" pbpID="RY@P5243" pdt="2016-06-08T04:29:06"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:29:25" pbpID="RY@P5245" pdt="2016-06-08T04:29:29"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:29:38" pbpID="RY@P5247" pdt="2016-06-08T04:29:40"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:29:51" pbpID="RY@P5253" pdt="2016-06-08T04:29:54"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T04:30:08" pbpID="ER@P5261" pdt="2016-06-08T04:30:13"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T05:59:18" pbpID="POLS@P127" pdt="2016-06-08T05:59:18"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T06:00:28" pbpID="POLS@POLS31P" pdt="2016-06-08T06:00:28"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T06:01:19" pbpID="POLS@POLS41P" pdt="2016-06-08T06:01:19"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T06:01:41" pbpID="POLS@POLS316P" pdt="2016-06-08T06:01:41"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T06:01:56" pbpID="POLS@POLS318P" pdt="2016-06-08T06:01:56"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T06:02:09" pbpID="POLS@POLS320P" pdt="2016-06-08T06:02:09"/>
    <pbpData pat="2016-06-08T06:02:16" pbpID="BIA@POLS322P" pdt="2016-06-08T06:02:16"/>
</rct:st>
```

I am new to Scala, but from what I've been reading around, there is an easy way (i.e., in few lines of code) to parse this and store into a Car object  attributes like an ID ("Number" in the rat:st tag) and a list of checkpoints (the "pbpData" lines, each of them identified by a node ID and two time variables).

Furthermore, do you think there is a way to save those times in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss with Scala as Date attributes? I was searching around but only found a [tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/java/simpledateformat-convert-date-to-string-formatted-parse) for changing the Date/Time format in Java, that only really explains how to change the way a Date we have is displayed, whereas I wish to do the contrary: saving this funnily written date/time as a valid Scala time.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

The xtract library (https://github.com/lucidsoftware/xtract) may be useful.

In your case you could do something like

```
case class Car(pat: String, pbpID: String, pdt: String)
object Car {
  implicit val reader: XmlReader[Car] = (
    attribute[String]("pat") and
    attribute[String]("pbpID") and
    attribute[String]("pdt")
  )(apply _)
}
```

And then you could get a sequence of them with something like

```
XMlReader.of[Seq[Car]].read(xml \\ "pbpData")
```

There is a blog post that goes into more detail [here](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/07/12/introducing-xtract-a-new-xml-deserialization-library-for-scala/).

Discalaimer: I wrote most of Xtract, and the mentioned blog post, and am an employee of Lucid Software.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Scala XML parser should do good for couple of hundred lines of XML (there are other XML parsers that are probably better for more demanding cases):

```
case class Car(pat: String, pbpID: String, pdt: String)
val xml = scala.xml.XML.loadString(<your xml as string or use loadFile>)
xml \\ "pbpData" map { node => 
  Car(node \\ "@pat" text, node \\ "@pbpID" text, node \\ "@pdt" text)
}
```

This will extract the data, but in order to convert dates to date objects I would suggest the jodatime as the best option for parsing ISO-dates.